# use getter setter with static function

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I try to use getter/ setter with static function.

Inside a mxml file, I try to get http service like that :

```
EventColorByDayModel.acListeVac(event.result.ListeVac.VacPeriode);
```

Indeed, I need to use result to poulate arraycollection inside  EventColorByDayModel.

See, below all my class:

```
package
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    public class EventColorByDayModel
    {

        private static var _acListeVac:ArrayCollection;

        public static function get acListeVac():ArrayCollection
        {
            return _acListeVac;
        }

        public static function set acListeVac(value:ArrayCollection):void
        {
            _acListeVac = value;
        }




        public static function getEventColorByDate(date:Date):uint
        {
            var result:uint = 0xE3EBF6;

            // Store renderer

            for each ( var item:Object in _acListeVac )
            {

                if (( item.dateMySQLDeb.time <=date.time )&&( date.time<=item.dateMySQLFin.time ))
                    result = uint(item.sColor);
            }


            return result;
        }


        public function EventColorByDayModel()
        {
        }

    }
}
```

But, in that case, an error appear with message, "impossible to access to acListeVac with a ref static Class".
I try to translate message error french to english. I hope, it's comprehensive.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a setter (specified by the set keyword), you just set the value like any other variable. So try this instead of the first line of code you have up there:

```
EventColorByDayModel.acListeVac = event.result.ListeVac.VacPeriode;
```

Comment: thanks indeed, it works. I use a lot getter and setter but I have no experience with static variable, so...